# How to authenticate with email on ldap3

Tags: python, authentication, ldap3

Is there a way to use email on ldap authentication instead of cn ?

I have tried with "cn=test,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org" and it works, but i want to use the email test@example.org.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `mail=test@example.org,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org`, depending on your LDAP Server the field might have a different name.

Comment: @ivvija  it's not working. the error message is invalidCredentials